# How do I insert and update to two different table at the same time

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to update into one table but i would also like to insert into another table which is all inside one database. Is it possible to do it in one submission or of course i can do it the easier way which is to seperate insert and update. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR); 

include("global.php");

if ($officer_name && $carno && $purpose && $schedule_date && $schedule_time 
&& $schedule_location)
{

$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db); 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update FEofficer set carno=?, purpose=?, 
schedule_date=?, schedule_time=?, schedule_location=? where 
officer_name=?");
$stmt1 = $mysqli1->prepare("INSERT INTO schedule (carno, purpose, 
schedule_date, schedule_time, schedule_location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $carno, $purpose, $schedule_date, 
$schedule_time, $schedule_location, $officer_name);
$stmt1->bind_param("sssss", $carno, $purpose, $schedule_date, 
$schedule_time, $schedule_location);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$result1 = $stmt1->execute();

if ($result1 == true && $stmt1->affected_rows>0) {      

     echo "<b>". $check . "</b><br>";

 }

if ($result == true && $stmt->affected_rows>0) {        
echo "<b>". $check . "</b><br>";
echo "<h2>You have successfully make a change!</h2><br>";
echo "<h3>Click <a href='distribute.php'>Here</a> to proceed back.</h3>
<br>";
}
else
{
echo "<h3>No Changes has been made</h3>";
echo '<p><h2>Please <a href="distribute.php">Click Here</a> to go back</h2>
</p>';  

}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
$stmt1->close();
$mysqli1->close();
}
else 
{
echo '<p>Please <a href="distribute.php">Click Here</a> to go back</p>';    
}

?>
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: you should be checking for `sql` errors to you know

Comment: I would recommend you look into [PDO transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) or [Mysqli transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php), since they basicly give you what you need. They allow you to specify which actions should be done and will only be committed once you specify that it should - what's really cool about transactions is that you can rollback the changes incase of an error or exception - which means that if you have relational data this is the way to go aswell.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve your objective

1) Use MySQL After Update Trigger: Since the values updated in the first table are the same, which are to be inserted into second table, using After Update trigger is the best way to do this. This will require your PHP code to fire the first query only. The insert query(second one), automatically gets fired by the trigger.

2) Wrap your PHP Update and Insert statements under PHP Transactional statements.
For Example:

```
try {

$db->beginTransaction();


$db->query('first query');//your first query
$db->query('second query');//Your second Query

$db->commit();
 } catch (Exception $e) {
//means something wrong with the operation, so both queries would roll back
$db->rollback();
}
```

This approach makes sure the atomicity of your transaction and helps maintain consistency across your DB

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow this process.

```
<?php
$carno = $this->input->post('carno');
$purpose = $this->input->post('purpose');
$schedule_date = $this->input->post('schedule_date');
$schedule_time = $this->input->post('schedule_time');
$schedule_location = $this->input->post('schedule_location');
$arr = array('carno'=>$carno,'purpose'=>$purpose,'schedule_date'=>$schedule_date,'schedule_time'=>$schedule_time,'schedule_location'=>$schedule_location);
$data = $this->db->insert('schedule',$arr);
if($data){
  $val = $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('schedule',$arr);
}
?>
```